# Copy JavaFX runtime with Ant

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I want to make a self-contained javafx app, but can't undestand how to extract java and javafx runtime to my jar with ant. So i'm adding this to my Ant script

```
 <target name="build" depends="compile">
    <fx:application id="GoL" mainClass="app.gol.GoL"/>
    <fx:jar destfile="${out.dir.dist}/${app.jar.name}">
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${java.home}/lib" includes="**/rt.jar" />
            <fx:fileset dir="${java.home}/lib" includes="**/fxrt.jar" />
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:application refid="GoL"/>
        <fileset dir="${out.dir.classes}"/>
    </fx:jar>
</target>
```

It just copies rt jars into my jar, but still crashes on systems without java runtime. How to fix it and use *rt.jar from my executable jar?

Comment: This would be more successful (and legal)  if you prompt the user to upgrade to a Java that has JavaFX included.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You are right, but without included runtime i can't distribute my app through the AppStore.

Comment: What 'AppStore'?  Are you referring to Android?  If so, add it as a tag.  And as an aside, that excuse does not make it legal.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, I'm refering to desktop application on JavaFX for MacOs AppStore. I Want to make a self-contained executable jar file bundled in DMG with java runtime in it.